# Connecting two routers via a LAN to WAN without lan cable (wirelessly)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

New tenants moved in and my neighbor wants to connect their router (upstairs) with the tenants downstairs via a lan to wan connection, however there is absolutely no way to run a cable from upstairs to downstairs. Is there a way perhaps to connect those two routers via a lan to wan method wirelessly?

Comment: What is the reason you want to use a LAN to WAN connection? Is it to protect the new network? (LAN-to-WAN connections protect the network that's getting Internet access, not the network that's providing it! The LAN has full access to the WAN because normally the WAN is an ISP.)

Comment: To be clear, this is probably an XY question. If the thinking is "we need to use a LAN to WAN connection to protect the existing tenant's private LAN" then it won't work. With a LAN to WAN connection, the WAN is the side giving Internet access and the LAN is the side that's protected.

Answer (score 0):

This is the a case for a wireless bridge. Some consumer-grade Wi-Fi routers can bet set to bridge this way, but it will not be through the WAN interface. If this router does not have the ability to function as a wireless bridge, then most of the companies manufacturing consumer-grade network equipment sell wireless bridges.

Bridging the two networks actually places all the devices on one LAN.

Comment: I've heard about wireless bridges but I have also heard that you will have to disable DHCP to the router hosting it. Is that true?

Comment: If you have a bridge, you don't do things like DHCP. The DHCP server for the LAN will run DHCP for the whole LAN, which has been expanded to include what is bridged. That DHCP server is probably in the consumer-grade router for the LAN, but that would not be the bridge.

Comment: I see, what has also been put to my attention is that the tenants along with their 4 children (6 people in total going to use the internet) each of them love doing different things on the internet he wants QoS enforced. Would this also be possible on the wireless bridge?

Comment: Real QoS isn't supported on consumer-grade equipment, and Wi-Fi has particular problems with QoS since the Wi-Fi protocol enforces a different mechanism to share the airwaves, even with other devices on the same frequency that are not part of the Wi-Fi LAN. Each wireless device on the same frequency must yield to other devices on the same frequency.

Comment: Oh so any other alternatives for QoS in this case?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by QoS. QoS is a huge subject that includes marking of IP packets, setting up various queues, using things like RED to prevent TCP global synchronization. policing, and traffic shaping. Wi-Fi, like ethernet, is a layer-2 protocol which does not look at the packets, so it will never see the packet markings. Only one Wi-Fi device can speak at a time, and the Wi-Fi protocol dictates how that works.

Comment: @MichaelBrakutt He probably wants QoS enforced because he doesn't understand what it does. The thing he probably wants to avoid congesting is the inbound Internet bandwidth -- which packets the ISP puts on the wire -- but that would require the ISP to run QoS.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to run a network cable, I suspect they have concrete floors between the levels or an architecture that probably also limits wireless range. I would first test if WiFi is able to effectively traverse between the floors. This coupled with heavy wireless usage may make this impracticable.

Secondly, while there may not be a way to run a wire from one floor to the other, likely there is a way to run the cable to a common point.  Think of how the electric wires or cable tv leave the floors and they all have to plug into the central junction.  See if you can do ethernet over coax at the junction point.  But again you may be limited in getting permission to hack the junction box.